# Error starting MongoDB in windows 7 [32-bit]

Tags: mongodb, windows-7, 32-bit

I followed a [blog(link)](http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/05/27/how-to-install-mongodb-on-windows/) to install and configure MongoDB in my system[*Windows 7 32 bit*].

As per blogger said, I have download **mongodb-win32-i386-2.6.5** and extract to *D:/mongodb/* and followed the [blog](http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/05/27/how-to-install-mongodb-on-windows/)

Upto installation everything alright, but when I try to *start service* using following command,

```
 D:\mongodb\bin>net start MongoDB
```

I got error response as,

```
System error 2 has occurred.

The system cannot find the file specified.
```

How to solve this ?

---

### Update : Log File

> 2014-11-19T16:43:25.356+0530 [DataFileSync] flushing diag log
>
> 2014-11-19T16:43:25.403+0530 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=5128 port=27017 dbpath=D:\mongodb\data 32-bit host=AVVENIRE-JAVA
>
> 2014-11-19T16:43:25.403+0530 [initandlisten]
>
> 2014-11-19T16:43:25.403+0530 [initandlisten] ** NOTE: This is a 32 bit MongoDB binary.
>
> 2014-11-19T16:43:25.403+0530 [initandlisten] **       32 bit builds are limited to less than 2GB of data (or less with --journal).
>
> 2014-11-19T16:43:25.403+0530 [initandlisten] **       See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/32bit
>
> 2014-11-19T16:43:25.404+0530 [initandlisten]
>
> 2014-11-19T16:43:25.404+0530 [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows XP SP3
>
> 2014-11-19T16:43:25.404+0530 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.1
>
> 2014-11-19T16:43:25.404+0530 [initandlisten] git version: 4b95b086d2374bdcfcdf2249272fb552c9c726e8
>
> 2014-11-19T16:43:25.404+0530 [initandlisten] build info: windows sys.getwindowsversion(major=6, minor=0, build=6002, platform=2, service_pack='Service Pack 2') BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
>
> 2014-11-19T16:43:25.404+0530 [initandlisten] allocator: system
> 2014-11-19T16:43:25.404+0530 [initandlisten] options: { config: "d:\mongodb\mongo.config", diaglog: 3, net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, storage: { dbPath: "D:\mongodb\data", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "D:\mongodb\log\mongo.log", quiet: true } }
>
> 2014-11-19T16:43:25.483+0530 [initandlisten] journal dir=D:\mongodb\data\journal
>
> 2014-11-19T16:43:25.484+0530 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
>
> 2014-11-19T16:43:25.770+0530 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
>
> 2014-11-19T16:44:25.439+0530 [DataFileSync] flushing diag log
>
> 2014-11-19T16:45:25.361+0530 [DataFileSync] flushing diag log
>
> 2014-11-19T16:46:25.360+0530 [DataFileSync] flushing diag log
>
> 2014-11-19T16:46:31.869+0530 [conn1] terminating, shutdown command received
>
> 2014-11-19T16:46:31.869+0530 [conn1] dbexit: shutdown called
>
> 2014-11-19T16:46:31.869+0530 [conn1] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
>
> 2014-11-19T16:46:31.869+0530 [conn1] closing listening socket: 540
>
> 2014-11-19T16:46:31.869+0530 [conn1] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
>
> 2014-11-19T16:46:31.869+0530 [conn1] flushing diag log
>
> 2014-11-19T16:46:31.869+0530 [conn1] shutdown: going to close sockets...
>
> 2014-11-19T16:46:31.870+0530 [conn1] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
>
> 2014-11-19T16:46:31.870+0530 [conn1] shutdown: lock for final commit...
>
> 2014-11-19T16:46:31.870+0530 [conn1] shutdown: final commit...
>
> 2014-11-19T16:46:31.873+0530 [conn1] shutdown: closing all files...
>
> 2014-11-19T16:46:31.873+0530 [conn1] closeAllFiles() finished
>
> 2014-11-19T16:46:31.873+0530 [conn1] journalCleanup...
>
> 2014-11-19T16:46:31.889+0530 [conn1] removeJournalFiles
>
> 2014-11-19T16:46:31.891+0530 [conn1] shutdown: removing fs lock...
>
> 2014-11-19T16:46:31.891+0530 [conn1] dbexit: really exiting now
>
> 2014-11-19T16:47:08.985+0530 ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
>
> 2014-11-19T16:47:08.985+0530 Trying to install Windows service 'MongoDB'
>
> 2014-11-19T16:47:08.985+0530 There is already a service named 'MongoDB', aborting

---

### Update 2(result of @disposer's suggestion):

[image]

Comment: Would you please share the logs. Moreover running on 32 bit version is not at all advisable.

Comment: @vmr I have updated logs in my question, please take a look and help me...(i have no idea about NoSql db)

Comment: Hmm better try with a 64bit version of MongoDB. Then start it from bin folder with 'mongod.exe'

Comment: @vmr But its not compatible 64-bit MongoDB on 32-bit Windows, can you help me to do with Windows 32 - bit

Comment: You can start a bounty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run Command window as administrator and run `net delete MongoDB`

For running mongo as a service use this:

```
C:\mongodb\bin\mongod --bind_ip  0.0.0.0 --logpath  "C:\Data\db\log.txt"  --logappend  --dbpath  "C:\Data\db"  --port 27017 --serviceName "MongoDB" --serviceDisplayName "MongoDB" --install
```

then run Command window as administrator and run `net start MongoDB`

Comment: When running mongo as a service as u said, getting response as, `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect`

Comment: Oh, my bad change C:\mongodb\bin\mongod" to C:\mongodb\bin\mongod, useless "

Comment: I have updated the result I got with your suggestion updated in my question, please take a look...

Comment: I see no error, just warnings, check your services from control panel and check for MongoDb service, it should be there

Comment: Add `--journal` to command and remove `--bind_ip  0.0.0.0` from it, see what happens, just run command as administrator

Comment: service has been added with --bind_ip 0.0.0.0 itself... Thank you.

Comment: Should it be 'sc delete...' and not 'net delete'?

Answer (score 6):

Download from this link @ http://downloads.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-i386-v3.2-latest-signed.msi?_ga=1.10304565.1436936475.1490595203

After installation in E: drive, run mongod command with options
 @ **E:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>**
*mongod --storageEngine=mmapv1 --dbpath C:\data\db*

Observe, two options are necessary to be installed without errors, specially for 32-bit, --storageEngine=mmapv1 and create a directory in OS drive(c:) only as --dbpath C:\data\db

Keep your server running at command prompt, install mongobooster from http://s3.mongobooster.com/download/3.5/mongobooster-3.5.3.exe for GUI to manage mongodb.
and connect to local database..try samples @ https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGDQ5DrbIl20Zu9hx1IjeVhO

Answer (score 4):

I got it working like this..

1. Install the latest [msi](https://www.mongodb.org/dl/win32/i386) version.
2. Create the folders c:\data\db
3. In my bin directory (C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin), I ran **mongod --storageEngine=mmapv1 --dbpath C:\data\db** using CMD.
4. Opened up a new CMD window (Keeping the one from 1st step still running) and traveled to the same bin directory (C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin) and then ran mongo.exe

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

in log file if it shows this"There is already a service named 'MongoDB', sleeping and retrying" that mean you are reinstalling mongodb.for resolve this problem just run

1. mongod --remove in command prompt in bin folder.it will remove service MongoDB.
2. then run mongod --directoryperdb --dbpath C:\mongodb\data\db --logpath C:\mongodb\log\mongo.log --logappend --install.
3. and the last command net start MongoDB will run MongoDB service.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with MongoDB 3.2 for 32 bit.

1. Try to make new `db` folder
2. Copy-paste your database from old db folder ( there are 2 files )
3. Connect it with new db folder using `cmd`

You won't loss your database. It had happened with me twice. I don't why it happened